# Facebook Graph API: Architecture to get to the "ads_read" token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to automate some processes with the Facebook Graph API but I am quite missing some parts in that flow, even though I read through the documentation a couple of times. So I was truly hoping someone can give me a shoulder on the architecture of how to get access to the "ad_reads" token and some other variables.

First of all my language is javascript, but I don't need any code, per se, just some tips and tricks on how to manage my flow.

What I have: I am a user. I have been granted access to an ads manager business page in Facebook. I can read all the data there in the Facebook's dashboard.

How I created the app so far:
 1. I have a simple login where I can get my facebook id.
 2. I have created an APP in "developers". It also has access to the ads manager business page on Facebook.
 3. To read the "insights" of the campaign in the ads manager, I need to do the following API call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<AD_CAMPAIGN_ID>/insights?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

I use the last API_VERSION. So Now I need to programmatically get the AD_CAMPAIGN_ID and the ACCESS_TOKEN.

My question is, how do I get all the AD_CAMPAIGN_IDs, that my user, with id=1234 has? And how do I get that ACCESS_TOKEN? I don't want to get it manually, I know where from in the APP(that I have in developers), so I assume I must get it from the:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Thank you very much for all the help I will get!